# Attribute not found with VichuploaderBundle in Symfony 6

Tags: php, attributes, symfony6, vichuploaderbundle

I followed the bundle configuration details but I still have the same problem :

```
Attribute class "Vich\uploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation\Uploadable" not found
```

here is the configuration file 'vich_uploader.yaml'.

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    metadata:
        type: attribute

    mappings:
        products:
            uri_prefix: /images/products
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/products'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\SmartUniqueNamer
```

here the Produicts entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProduitsRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\True_;
use Vich\uploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;


#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProduitsRepository::class)]
#[Vich\Uploadable]
class Produits
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $nom = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)]
    private ?int $star = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $prix = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $is_publish;

    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: 'products', fileNameProperty: 'imageName', size: 'imageSize')]
    private ?File $imageFile = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: True)]
    private ?string $imageName = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $Update_At = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $Create_At;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Create_At = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $this->is_publish = false;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStar(): ?int
    {
        return $this->star;
    }

    public function setStar(int $star): self
    {
        $this->star = $star;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrix(): ?int
    {
        return $this->prix;
    }

    public function setPrix(int $prix): self
    {
        $this->prix = $prix;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isIsPublish(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->is_publish;
    }

    public function setIsPublish(bool $is_publish): self
    {
        $this->is_publish = $is_publish;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

        if (null !== $imageFile) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->Update_At = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }
    public function getImageName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    public function setImageName(string $imageName): self
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdateAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->Update_At;
    }

    public function setUpdateAt(?\DateTimeImmutable $Update_At): static
    {
        $this->Update_At = $Update_At;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreateAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->Create_At;
    }

    public function setCreateAt(\DateTimeImmutable $Create_At): static
    {
        $this->Create_At = $Create_At;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I cleared the project cache with the command: `symfony console cache:clear`
then Check that the bundles.php file contains the entry for the VichUploaderBundle bundle : `Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle::class => ['all' => true],`, and made a dependency update.

but the result is always the same, as the proof is here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31nCb.png)